# UltraGridCell index

Tags: c#, ultrawingrid

How can I get the index of the currently selected cell ? (index from the row containing it).
It would be logic if it had a property like this

```
myUltraGridView.ActiveCell.Index;
```

But it does not exists. I would like to avoid having to do something like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < myUltraGridView.ActiveRow.Cells.Count; i++)
   if(myUltraGridView.ActiveRow.Cells(i) == myUltraGridView.ActiveCell)
      return i;
```

Any idea how I can access it ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the actual index or the visible index? Both of these come from the cell's column.

Try these:

(Actual)

```
myUltraGridView.ActiveCell.Column.Index
```

(Visible location in grid)

```
myUltraGridView.ActiveCell.Column.Header.VisiblePosition
```

Answer (score 1):

There's also the `Index` property on the `UltraGridRow` class, if you're looking for the row's index.

```
ultraGrid1.ActiveCell.Row.Index
```